# Socket communication: can send fail when receive succeeded?

Tags: sockets, tcp

As far as I understand TCP/IP, it doesn't give any guarantees for acknowledging whether the receiving side (B) has really received any data from the sender (A). E.g.:

```
A: socket.write(1);
B: socket.read(); // this can fail and A wouldn't know unless B sends an ACK
```

I've been wondering, is the opposite situation also possible?

```
A: socket.write(1); // can this fail while B does receive "1" without any error?
B: socket.read();
```

Comment: Of course it can't. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP: The source of my concern was that I'd seen situations where write/send would succeed even if immediately followed by broken connection (i.e. data wouldn't be received on the other side) so I wasn't sure in what situations write/send operation *can* fail. SergeyA's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: This question seems 100%valid and I have experienced this. write to socket failed but message was received. Most of time I noticed failure was due to timeout OR less space in send buffer. adding retry logic helped to get rid of it to some extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 different possible outcomes of a `send()` call:

1. `send()` returns the number of bytes equal to it's 3rd argument (len). This means, message was successfully put into TCP stack, and now the stack will do it's best to deliver it.
2. `send()` returns -1. It means, there was a local-detectable error. For example, socket is not connected, message is too big to be passed atomically, etc. Nothing was sent. `errno` will have the actual reason for the error.
3. `send()` returns a non-negative number, not equal to it's 3rd argument. This means, `send()` was not able to send the whole message, but sent a part of it. Most likely reason is a non-blocking `send()` call, and there is no room in send buffer to fit the rest. errno will be likely set to EAGAIN (EWOULDBLOCK). This means, some part of the message was sent, so receiever can see it.
4. Application receives SIGPIPE signal. This means, that the socket was shutdown on the other side, and SIGPIPE was not suppressed. Nothing was sent.

Comment: Thank you, your answer left me no place for any doubts! Now it's really hard to imagine how the other side would receive proper data if the sender had gotten an error code.